How to satisfy stylelint "context" check, without causing gullp errors?
My code:
@media (min-width: 965px) {
    #my-class {
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
}

is causing stylelint to throw this error:
✖  Expected "context" media feature      media-feature-range-notation
             range notation

I tried their suggestion:
 @media (width >= 965px) {

but it just causes gulp to throw this error:
Error: unclosed parenthesis in media query expression


Queries like "@media (min-width: 965px) {" are an older method.
"@media (width >= 965px) {" is the newer way to specify the same query.
Our code base was still requiring node-sass, which is no longer supported. Updating our gulpfile.js to use "sass" instead of "node-sass" seemed to resolve the gulp error.
